# In an object, is that possible to extract the variable name of property value as string?

Tags: javascript, object, variables

As per the title, for example, assume there is a magical function (magicalFunc()) that can achieve this:

```
const myLovelyArray= [3,1,5,10]
const myObject = {property1 :myLovelyArray}
console.log( magicalFunc(myObject.property1) ) //Output: "myLovelyArray" (as string)
```

Is that possible and advisable??

I tried something suggested by ChatGPT:

```
function variableNameExtractor(variable) {
  const regex = /^[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z0-9_$]*/;
  const match = regex.exec(variable.toString());
  return match ? match[0] : null;
}

const myVariable = 2;
const variableName = variableNameExtractor(myVariable);
console.log(variableName);
```

However, it outputs null, it doesn't work

Comment: `magicalFunc` cannot work. There is no link *from* a value *to* a variable. Consider `a = [1, 2, 3]; b = a`. Then what would `magicalFunc` output? Which then explains why ChatGPT is trash. And the answer it gave. It's *not possible at all* but it didn't stop it. At any rate, what you're asking is probably [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what task requires you to look up the variable some value belongs to? How do you expect to use that information, given than the string name of the variable is almost entirely useless?

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. There is no link from a *value* to which variable stored it. `magicalFunc` cannot be implemented in a sensible way.